# xml parsing issue encoding error

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-3.4

I have an xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tw>
    <tweet>
        <yazi>atılacak tweet 1</yazi>
        <resim>resim.png</resim>
    </tweet>
    <tweet>
        <yazi>atılacak tweet 2</yazi>
        <resim>yok</resim>
    </tweet>
</tw>
```

I'm trying to read it with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ett

e = ett.parse("tweet.xml").getroot()
```

But I get this error,

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML
>   declaration is incorrect: line 1, column 31

Why? How can I fix this, I searched a lot and xml file looks ok. I don't understand why I can't read the file.

Comment: Can't replicate. I copy pasted in to a file and ran this code without issues.

Comment: @idjaw Well I get this error I'm working on Windows

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. I copied that XML piece you pasted in to a file. I copied that code and ran it and it is working fine for me. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: You put them into an XML file and ran without error? How so? Why I get this error then.

Comment: The only difference is that I am not on Windows.

Comment: @idjaw Python 3.4 also? This is so weird.

Comment: I tested this on Py3.5

Answer (score 0):

you probably have an invalid utf-8 char in your file, e.g. the xml file is iso-8859-1 encoded... or you can try utf-8 instead of UTF-8

Comment: @GLHF-Is the posted XML the original problem-causing file?

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ett


e = ett.parse("tweet.xml").getroot()

print(e.tag)

for altindakiler in e:
    print(altindakiler.tag, altindakiler.attrib)
```

Comment: This might fix the bug, but doesn't answer the question of why it happens in the first place.